# Video editing in android studio

Tags: java, android, video, documentation, video-editing

i'm looking on some documentation and examples as to how i should get started creating a video editing application. Been having a hard time finding anything useful, anyone who can guide me to something?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Follow this Github example and try to understand every functionality of this example.

First Github Example Link : [Video Editing example](https://github.com/JaySardhara/Video-Editor)

Second Github Example Link :[Video Editing Example](https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/FFmpeg-Video-Editor-Android)

Hope it will help you...